# Query to find null of specific column with multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, exists

Using my example below, I would like to find all the users that have a null value in a column even though they have multiple entries in that table. So for example I have a table like this:

| ID | userid | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | a | null | b |
| 2 | user1 | b | a | b |
| 3 | user2 | a | null | b |
| 4 | user2 | b | null | b |

I would like to return user2 only since it has col2 that has nothing filled in for any of the rows. However, how do I create a query that will not bring me back user1 because user1 does have a value for col2 in one of the rows.  User1 keeps getting pulled because it does have a row where col2 is null.  Basically any userId that nothing populated in col2 in any of the rows in this table.  If a userId does have a value in col2, don't return that userId.

I tried something like this:

```
select distinct(a.userid) from User a
group by a.userid 
having a.col is null
```

Comment: Are you expecting both user rows tot be returned? Try using `NOT EXISTS` and if that doesn't work, add the query you tried to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.userid
FROM User u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User u2 WHERE u2.userid = u1.userid AND u2.col2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the user, you can use aggregation:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having max(col1) is null or
       max(col2) is null or
       max(col3) is null;
```

`MAX()` (or most aggregation functions) return `NULL` only when all values are `NULL`.  You can also use `COUNT()`:

```
having count(col1) = 0 or
       count(col2) = 0 or
       count(col3) = 0;
```